# Is it senseful to query an OLAP cube with DAX?

Tags: olap, business-intelligence, dax

From what I understand it's made to be used on Excel that is bidimensional.
Or not?
Probably it's a stupid question but it's my bachelor degree final exam and I'm getting paranoid

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dax is a multidimensional query language as MDX. So, definitively, it's not a bad idea. DAX has not been designed for Excel but for SSAS tabular. You use it from Excel to query your model in SSAS tabular or Power Pivot (Excel plug-in).

On the other hand, MDX is a bit more powerful but also a bit more difficult to write.  If your query is relatively straightforward you could go for DAX.

At the end, between DAX and MDX, it will be just a question of are you familiar or not with this language.

PS: DAX is not supported on all versions of SSAS and is not supported by other Olap cubes

Comment: thank you so much, i never heard about DAX or MDX before, the just left here with an old undocumented code an no explanation :o